# makefile on unix vi editor how to create one

Tags: makefile

```
imdb1: assignment1.o treecomp.o treefunction.o
        gcc -lm -o imdb1 assignment1.o treecomp.o treefunction.o

assignment1.o: assignment1.c assignment1.h
        gcc -Wall -ansi assignment1.c

treecomp.o: treecomp.c treecomp.h
        gcc -Wall -ansi treecomp.c

treefunction.o: treefunction.c treefunction.h
        gcc -Wall -ansi treefunction.c
```

when i go make
it gives me this error

```
treefunction.c:6: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
treefunction.c:7: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
treefunction.c:8: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
treefunction.c:9: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:10: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:11: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:12: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
treefunction.c:22: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
treefunction.c:34: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:38: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:51: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:55: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:77: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
```

it compiles fine on cmd but when compiled with makefile it give out that error

can anyone please help

Comment: It is an error in your `treefunction.c` and in the way you compile it.

Comment: [Simplify `treefunction.c` as much as you can](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then post it here.

Answer (score 0):

This command `gcc -Wall -ansi assignment1.c` will try to generate the executables `a.out` instead of just compiling and generating the object file.

Change as below for all the targets containing the object files and check once again.

```
gcc -c -Wall -ansi assignment1.c
```